# Getting undefined value for radio button input

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form I have following radio button input:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_1" value="Efectivo" checked>Efectivo
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_2" value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta
    </label>
  </div>
```

I am trying to get the selected value as follows:

```
var forma_pago = $("#opciones input:radio:checked").val();
alert (forma_pago);
```

But I am getting as result "Undefined"

what is wrong there?

Comment: You are using #opciones to get val but that's the name not the id.

Comment: $("#opciones_1 input[type=radio]:checked") would be more along the lines of what you're trying for, but why not just $("#opciones_1")?

Comment: `the wrong there...`  is this selector `#opciones input:radio:checked`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is wrong. `opciones` is name not `id`. Try like following.

```js
var forma_pago = $(":radio[name=opciones]:checked").val();
alert(forma_pago);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_1" value="Efectivo" checked>Efectivo
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_2" value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 var forma_pago = $("input[name=opciones]:checked").val();
    alert (forma_pago);
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an element with the id of `opciones`. If you still want to be specific, use the `attribute equals selector` instead:

```js
var forma_pago = $("input[name='opciones']:radio:checked").val();
console.log(forma_pago);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">

  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_1" value="Efectivo" checked>Efectivo
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_2" value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta
    </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alert($('input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert ($("input[name=opciones]:checked").val());
$("input[name=opciones]").on('click',function() {
alert ($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-sm-12">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_1" value="Efectivo" checked>Efectivo
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="opciones" id="opciones_2" value="Tarjeta">Tarjeta
    </label>
  </div>
```